# Is there a way to verify if an email address is a valid Paypal email

Tags: ios, paypal

I'd like to verify the email entered by the user if it is a valid PayPal email or not without taking the customer to the PayPal screen. I want to do this from code and on the backend if possible.

I found [some information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) related to my need but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my answer using this .

```
 _postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"emailAddress=%@&matchCriteria=%@",email,@"NONE"];

request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID"];
[request addValue:@"WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD"];
[request addValue:@"AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE"];
[request addValue:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID"];
[request addValue:@"NV" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT"];
[request addValue:@"JSON" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT"];
```

Comment: The endpoint requires firstName and lastName - are you sure this works?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/

Comment: yes it is totally working for me ...copy paste whole code and just send the email in this code....

Comment: where is the _postData added to the request?

Comment: I know it's been a while but you might want to remove the secret key, the signature and the password from the code posted above. You know, just to stay safe.

Comment: Hello Peter , thanks for your concern, The secret key and other information mention above is provided by paypal itself.

Answer (score 2):

The information you have found is the correct way to verify the PayPal account.
GetVerifiedStatus is one of the API of Adaptive Accounts.
Please refer to the link below for the details of Adaptive Accounts.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/gs_AdaptiveAccounts/

To use GetVerifiedStatus API, you will need to go to the site below to apply for an APP ID which should be used when you call Adaptive Accounts APIs.
https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications
Go to the site above, login and click "New App", then fill in the form base on your needs.
Make sure to check the "Get Verified Status" checkbox under "Adaptive Accounts".
After you applied it, APP review team will review your application, if any update, they will leave a message on this site.

Comment: hi thanks mate....i registered the same and get my sandbox and live app id from the developer account and also checked the "Get Verified Status" option....after that what need to be done the link in the start you provided gives the code related to web....kindly guide me what and how to do next...

Comment: Below is the SDK of Adaptive Accounts, there is sample code in SDK in which you can find how to use the API.
http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#adaptive-accounts

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)verifyEmail:email
{
[kappDelegate ShowIndicator];
NSMutableURLRequest *request ;
NSString*_postData ;
webservice=1;
_postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"emailAddress=%@&matchCriteria=%@",email,@"NONE"];
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID"];
[request addValue:@"WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD"];
[request addValue:@"AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE"];
[request addValue:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID"];
[request addValue:@"NV" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT"];
[request addValue:@"JSON" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT"];
[request setHTTPBody: [_postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(connection)
{
    if(webData==nil)
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data] ;
        NSLog(@"data");
    }
    else
    {
        webData=nil;
        webData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    }
    NSLog(@"server connection made");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"connection is NULL");
}
}
```

here is the full code that i am using right now... as it is in sandbox environment no need to change any key value just send the email using this method to verify email with paypal.